# How to keep a 2 year old entertained in the car on long road trips?

Tags: toddler, travel, toys, entertainment

Pls suggest some toys and strategies that have worked for you.

Comment: [The answers to this question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/how-can-we-make-a-long-road-trip-pleasant-for-a-toddler-and-the-parents?rq=1) may be useful.